# While loop split into multiple files . n output when printing

Tags: while-loop, header-files, declaration

its a simple while loop i' trying to split into multiple files in Xcode . code shows no error but i can not print

output . here is the code :

its a simple while loop i' trying to split into multiple files in Xcode . code shows  error in main.cpp  can not print

output . here is the code . what am i doing wrong ?

this is main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "loop.hpp"
using namespace std;



int main ()

{
  
    
   void w_loop (int i);
    
   cout << i << endl;
    
   
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

this what i have in header file loop.h :

int w_loop ();

this is decleration:  loop.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void w_loop (int i){
 
 
   i =0;
   while (i < 10)
        
   i++;
    
   cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: Which is it? `loop.h` or `loop.hpp`? `void w_loop(int i);` in `main` is not the way to call the function. Why does `w_loop` take an argument if you just immediately set it to zero? You should put the body of the while loop within braces.

Comment: its .hpp. if i do it like this #include "loop.h". then i get this error : 'loop.h' file not found . is Xode . couldn't make it it .h